# Netty NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() Blocked

Tags: java, spring, netty

my code in spring is:

```
group = SysUtil.isLinux()?new EpollEventLoopGroup():new NioEventLoopGroup();
```

and code block here, the thread can't continue, i use jstack, the thread is always here, but the thread state is runable:

```
"init_context_comm_t0" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5fdc889800 nid=0x27 in Object.wait() [0x00007f5fd7ffc000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at io.netty.util.NetUtil.(NetUtil.java:156)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
locked <0x00000000835e5868> (a java.util.Vector)
locked <0x00000000837abda8> (a java.util.Vector)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
locked <0x0000000083320da8> (a java.lang.Runtime)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:214)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.(Native.java:60)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.IovArray.(IovArray.java:57)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.(EpollEventLoop.java:60)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:106)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:64)
at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:91)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:78)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:59)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:43)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:36)
at com.sunyainfo.sunyacloud.communication.server.CommunicateEndpoint.(CommunicateEndpoint.java:46)
at com.sunyainfo.sunyacloud.communication.server.CommunicateEndpoint.init(CommunicateEndpoint.java:115)
at com.sunyainfo.sunyacloud.mvc.ContextListener$1.run(ContextListener.java:39)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Steps to reproduce
In the spring init code, call this:

```
group = SysUtil.isLinux()?new EpollEventLoopGroup():new NioEventLoopGroup();
```

Netty version

```
4.0.36.Final
```

JVM version (e.g. java -version)

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-8u141-b15-1~deb9u1-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
```

OS version (e.g. uname -a)

```
Linux debian 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Tips: i run this code in docker

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug... please open an issue in the netty issue tracker with a full-reproducer so we can have a look. Also you may want to upgrade your netty version just to rule out its not already fixed.

Comment: I just noticed the issue was already opened but after looking into it I am sure its fixes in 4.0.54.Final and later. See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/8094